# Multiply by random number each iteration

Tags: matlab

I'd like to multiply a random number vector `PT(n)=rand(1,n)` by a matrix `M(mxn)` but want to have a different random vector for each column multiplication. Is it possible in Matlab?

E.g. `PT=rand(1,4);`

```
`PT*(1 0 0 0;...
     0 0 0 1;... 
     0 1 0 0;...
     0 0 0 1);
```

but where PT changes for each column multiplication.  The only way I can think of is make `PT=rand(4,4)`and then take `diag(PT*M)` but it's very expensive if my matrix M is large.
Any thoughts?

Cheers

Suplemental
using @Nasser arrayfun code takes 3 times longer than a for loop. I see it's normal but why the big difference?

Comment: You can't multiply a `1`x `n` vector by a `m`x `n` matrix.  And wouldn't what you describe just result in a random vector anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood exactly what you are asking.

But if you mean you have a matrix of vectors, and you want to multiply another matrix by each one of these vectors then one way is to use `arrayfun`.

For example: Here we multiply a 5 by 4 matrix with 3 vectors, each is 4 by 1.

The result is 3 vectors, each is 5 by 1

```
pt = rand(4,3);
M  = rand(5,4);
r  = arrayfun(@(i) M*pt(:,i),1:size(pt,2),'UniformOutput',false)
```

gives

```
r = 

    [5x1 double]    [5x1 double]    [5x1 double]

cell2mat(r)

ans =

    0.1463    0.4386    0.4638
    0.4104    0.8105    0.6455
    0.9503    1.0145    1.0369
    1.3011    1.4583    1.5233
    0.4688    0.7405    0.7492
```

Comment: That's interesting but still makes `n` times more data than I need. I just need to the top row so don't want to make a huge matrix.  Can I specify which rows to multiply in that arrayfun eg. PT(:,i)*M(i,:)

Comment: I think a small modification of this will be just right:
r  = arrayfun(@(i) M(i,:)*pt(:,i),1:size(pt,2),'UniformOutput',false)

Comment: OK, if that works for you. But the above is a vector by vector multiplication now (you are multiplying a row vector by a column vector). You said in your question you wanted to multiply a matrix by a vector.  Either way, glad to be of help.

Comment: Thank you for your careful explanation.  I have implemented this and eventually found a for loop to be time saving... Could you comment on a case in which it would be better practice to use arrayfun rather than a loop?  A google search upholds the claim of speed, but doesn't give a good reason for one over the other. What do you think? Thanks

Comment: loops are fast now in Matlab (since 6.5). But this is just a styling issue. I like functional programming, and so arrayfun seems natural to me. You are applying a function on an array. So, any time you have a function, and list of things you want to apply this function on, you can either use vectorization (if possible), if not, then either use a loop or arrayfun (unless something like bsxfun ofcourse will do, then use that).  in arrayfun, the function you are applying can be a handle to the actual function, and so it is a flexible operation. use what feels better for you (all things equal).

Answer (score 0):

I ma not sure, but according to your example, it looks like you want to do a random permutation of the columns of PT. If that's the case, you can do:

```
PT=PT(:,randperm(size(PT,2)));
```

Comment: This permutes the columns in the array but can I make the values of the vector PT(1,4) vary randomly after every column multiplication with M(:,i)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you, how about

```
M = rand(4,4);     % your matrix
PT = rand(4,4);    % your random row vectors
rslt = sum(PT'.*M,2); % your desired result
```

Comment: Nice! Yes that solves the problems without for loops. In fact all I was looking for, as it turns out, was `PT'.*M`. Strange how the mind blocks out the simplest solutions.  It's actually made simplifications in other parts of the code too! Thanks again!